# jquery/ajax CORS request is returning a GET

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this ajax call to another domain:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $form.serialize(),  // serializes the form's elements.
        dataType: "jsonp",
        processData: false,
        jsonp: "callback",
           success: function(data)
           {   
           console.log("Passed it");
           console.log(callback(response));
           }
```

Even that the request is a post, I'm getting a GET with a very long URL, like this:
[http://example.com?param1='value'&param2="value",etc...](http://example.com?param1=%27value%27&param2=%22value%22,etc...).

This is my error: ERR_ABORTED 414 (Request-URI Too Long)

the problem is that my form is huge, it has like 40 different fields.

I'm using jsonp because it's a different domain and processData:false because I was having a callback on url.

Please help, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you making the AJAX request when a `form` element is submit? If so, it sounds like you've not prevented the standard form submission and that is sending a GET request instead of the POST coming from your AJAX. ***However*** using JSONP and `processData: false` will have absolutely no effect on the request if the CORS headers are not included in the *response* from the endpoint you're calling. You will need to add them there, assuming they don't exist already - which I'm guessing they don't otherwise you wouldn't have tried to use JSONP.

Comment: yes, it's an ajax request when form submit. The method of the form is POST too. My endpoint is on Laravel, i have added the headers on the middleware

Comment: The other issue is that you can only make GET requests using JSONP. This is by design and why your `type: "POST"` is being overridden

Comment: ohh ok, so I need to resolve the CORS issue if I wan't to send POST, right?

Comment: That's right. Then you can avoid the use of JSONP and sent the POST request as normal

Comment: thanks, I will try to solve the CORS issue then!